# Unable to mount external HDD with SABRENT Drive enclosure

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount, hard-drive

I am not necessarily new to Linux, but am trying to go all Linux.  I am trying to connect an external drive that is formatted freshly with NTFS.  The diver is 1TB.  I have tried using `sudo fdisk -l` to see drive and `sudo parted -l` but it is not seen.  I also ran `lsusb` and the drive was not listed.  If I go into disks, I see this:

[image: DISKS View]

[image: EXTERNAL DISK VIEW]

When I try to mount I get this:

```
sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdd /media/external
[sudo] password for user: 
Failed to read bootsector (size=0)
Failed to mount '/dev/sdd': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sdd' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to format you disk in disks tool? https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0wQb.png

Comment: If you are trying to go “all Linux” and the drive is freshly formatted why not reformat it to ext4? Backup any data you want to keep first though but if it’s freshly formatted I assume there is none.

Comment: You mix up disks (sdd) with partitions (sdd1).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is a controller bug

To lists block devices,open a Terminal:

```
> lsblk
```

probably you will see a raid0 FS (fake).

Fix using `mdadm`

> sudo mdadm --stop /dev/md(your-id)

open gparted,format the HDD then set FS label like device name.

now you can mount !